# return total of stmt->execute()

Tags: php, mysqli

How do I find out the number of rows return from a query when using stmt->prepare(); / stmt->execute();
In my example below, if i don't get any results back, i would like to display an nice message to the user

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thanks

**EDITED:**
as stated by @zerkms, there is a solution but, i was hoping for a solution that doesn't buffer the entire result set in the statement handle...

....

```
$selected_disc = array(1=>'disc1', 2=>'disc2', 3=>'disc3');

// show tracks for each disc in album
$sql = 'SELECT track_id, name FROM album WHERE album_id = ?';

foreach ($selected_disc as $key => $disc) {

    $stmt->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $key);
    $ok = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($trackid, $name);

    if( VALUES FOUND, SHOW !) {

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo $t_name;
        }

    } else {
        echo 'Nothing to display... blablabla';
    }

    $stmt->free_result(); // free the database resources for other queries
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method for that: [mysqli_stmt_num_rows() / mysqli_stmt::num_rows()](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)

Comment: i've read about that method... but, i was hoping for a solution that doesn't buffer the entire result set in the statement handle... the reason i've posted my quesion. If there are no other ways, i guess i'll have no choice to buffer the result set...

Comment: @Marco: 1) why did not you specify that in the question????? 2) Doesn't it work if you use it in the code you posted in the question?

Comment: @Marco .. but what is the issue with buffering? If they are there you are going to display them. If there is nothing then there is nothing to buffer.

Comment: @zerkms: sorry about that.. i agree, i should have specified that in my original question

Comment: @Marco: anyway, I agree with Phil: could you explain what issues do you experience with buffers?

Comment: no issues at all, it's more for learning purposes... i've researched the solution for an hour and couldn't find anything at all... that's why i thought that maybe someone new of a non-buffer solution... Like i said, i'm always trying to learn and test different solutions... Thanks again! I truly do appreciate all the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();

/* store result */
$stmt->store_result();

printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", $stmt->num_rows);
```